# How make scrolling function with Interface builder on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, interface

I wonder how is possible to make a view scroll, like in a table view.

I have a form that have several fields on it. I don't wanna buil it as a traditional table that drill-down.

Is not very large but because the main windows is a tab-bar I lack of a bit of vertical space. Also, when I try to fill a textfield get covered by the keywoard and I want that the focus move to the field and the view scrool, like in the safari way.

Answer (score 1):

Select the main form view in Interface Builder and choose Layout > Embed Objects in > Scroll View from the menu. You may have to adjust some connections to make everything work.